# Uploading WAR file to S3 using ingenieux beanstalk maven plugin hangs

Tags: maven, amazon-s3, beanstalk-maven-plugin

I am trying to upload a war into S3 using the Ingenieux beanstalk plugin. However it hangs trying to upload. Does anyone come across this anomaly?

I am following this tutorial here:
http://beanstalker.ingenieux.com.br/beanstalk-maven-plugin/usage.html

```
mvn beanstalk:upload-source-bundle
```

Here is the logs:

```
[WARNING] You should encrypt your passwords. See http://beanstalker.ingenieux.com.br/security.html for more information
[INFO] Target Path: s3://some-bucket/test-web2-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
[INFO] Uploading artifact file: C:\Users\Chin Boon\Documents\workstation\test-web2\target\test-web2-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
```

pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>br.com.ingenieux</groupId>
    <artifactId>beanstalk-maven-plugin</artifactId>

    <configuration>
        <s3Bucket>some-bucket</s3Bucket>
        <s3Key>${project.build.finalName}.war</s3Key>
        <!-- will save as s3://[bucket name]/artifactId-version-TIMESTAMP.war -->
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

We don't support too much the S3 Uploading (too slow, error prone), and suggest using fast-deploy instead.

$ mvn archetype:generate -Dfilter=elasticbeanstalk]

to get a sample pom to apply

Comment: Its an alternate method which uses the git deployment feature of AWS S3.

I haven't written too much about it, so thats the reason I haven't released 1.0. Btw, can you pastebin a full trace? The version it seems to be running seems quite outdated, as recent versions print out its status

Comment: Can you link me to a page where i can get the latest versions. 1.0-SNAPSHOT doesn't seem to resolve any dependencies for me.

Comment: Switch your version to the latest released: 0.2.9 - It should work like a charm

Answer (score 0):

Ok i think i know what the problem was.

This was required in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>br.com.ingenieux</groupId>
    <artifactId>beanstalk-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.2.9</version>
</dependency>
```